# Java EE injection based on type parameters

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, generics, cdi, java-ee-7

I'm trying to select a bean based on its ParameterizedType.  It looks like there are a phenomenal number of answers here with Google Guice-related solutions, but is this possible with Java EE 7?

```
public interface Handler<T> { ... }

@ApplicationScoped StringHandler implements Handler<String> { ... }
@ApplicationScoped IntegerHandler implements Handler<Integer> { ... }
```

Then in some other managed bean:

```
@Inject private Instance<Handler<?>> handlers;

public <T> Handler<T> handlerFor( Class<T> handledClass )
{
    // ???
}
```

So here's the select method in Instance that relates to types:

```
<U extends T> Instance<U> select(TypeLiteral<U> subtype, Annotation... qualifiers);
```

And the javadoc for TypeLiteral just says that you can do things like

```
 TypeLiteral<List<String>> stringListType = new TypeLiteral<List<String>>() {};
```

Which is terribly unhelpful, because I don't know the types at compile-time.  I do, however, have the Class object as the type parameter argument.

It seems that Guice can handle this just fine by constructing TypeLiteral objects for you.  Is there no similar facility in Java EE 7?

Comment: Any reason why you can't do `@Inject Handler<T> handler` ?

Comment: @John Because of type erasure the container won't know the type at runtime if I use type parameters and won't know which one to inject.  I'd love to pass it the Class at runtime, but there's no select(...) for it.

Comment: What does the class you're trying to inject into look like?

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but I was facing a similar issue and wanted to share my approach:

Instead of using `Instance.select` (which requires the TypeLiteral that can only be constructed during compile time), I simply iterated over all instances (using streams) and then checked for each instance if they "fit" using reflection:

```
@Inject
@Any
Instance<Handler<?>> instances;

//...
Handler<?> handler = this.instances.stream()
    .filter(it -> this.fits(it, handledClass))
    .findAny().orElse(null);
```

The implementation of the fits method is a bit - awkward - so to say (Note: Depending on the CDI implementation, it might need some adjustments!). Also, depending on the use case, a simple equality check might not be enough if the handlers should also support subclasses (instead, one could use `Class.isAssignableFrom` instead)!

```
private boolean fits(Class<?> clazz, Class<?> target)
{
    if (clazz == null)
      return false;
    
    Type[] genericInterfaces = clazz.getGenericInterfaces();
    
    boolean match = Arrays.stream(genericInterfaces)
        .filter(it -> it instanceof ParameterizedType)
        .map(it -> (ParameterizedType) it)
        .filter(it -> it.getRawType() == Handler.class)
        .anyMatch(it -> ((Class<?>) it.getActualTypeArguments()[0]) == target);
    
    if (match)
      return true;
    if (this.fits(clazz.getSuperclass(), target))
      return true;
    if (Arrays.stream(clazz.getInterfaces()).anyMatch(it -> this.fits(it, target)))
      return true;

    return false;
}
```

Note that the recursion is required because handler.getClass() will return the class of the CDI client proxy which unfortunately does not implement the interfaces of the base type in a generic way. Also, if we have the following construct, `FooHandlerImpl.class.getGenericInterfaces()` won't return `Handler<Foo>` unfortunately. So we need to traverse the hierarchy ourselves:

```
public interface FooHandler extends Handler<Foo> {  }
public class FooHandlerImpl implements FooHandler {  }
```

It might be a good idea to cache the results maybe.

Comment: Hi, just use `beanManager.getBeans + beanManager.getReference`. There is no need in `Instance` in our case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very well your question.

But perhaps you can obtain in runtime the generic type by

```
String typeName = handledClass.getClass().getTypeParameters()[0].getName();
```

Then create a generic annotation for each CDI Handler and switch based on the type:

```
Annotation qualifier = typeName.equalsIgnoreCase("String") ? new AnnotationLiteral<StrHandler>() {} : new AnnotationLiteral<IntHandler> (){};
```

And finally in your Instance do something like:

```
return handlers.select(qualifier).get();
```

EDIT: more info about generate the qualifiers annotation based on AnnotationLiteral on http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#_obtaining_a_contextual_instance_by_programmatic_lookup

And don't forget to use  @Any on your injection

```
   @Inject @Any Instance<Handler<?>> instance;
```

to avoid the default injection.

Comment: I think the closest I'd get is building an extension to automatically annotate my handler classes by looking at the type parameters and adding type literals during bean validation.  It's still a pain though, where all the information is available at runtime but I can't select it.  It would be ideal if the Instance class had a "select( Type... typeParameters )" and I could then pass in a list of classes.